# Azure Android custom login with JS back end

Tags: android, node.js, azure

I want to add an authentication with email and password in android app with back end on Azure(use Node.js). I read an [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/) about custom user authentication, but there is no anything about how to do it in android app. I try to use [this tutorial](http://chrisrisner.com/Authentication-with-Android-and-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services/), but maby it is too old becouse code from it is not compiled. So, who knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For Authenticating users, you can refer to the section [`How to: Authenticate users`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#authentication) of the offical doc [`How to use the Android client library for Mobile Services`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/), and the doc [`Add authentication to your Mobile Services Android app (JavaScript backend)`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-users/) shows more details.

The two topics show you how to authenticate users in Azure Mobile Services from your app with one or more of the following authentication providers: Google, Facebook, Twitter, Microsoft & Azure AD. I recommend you can try to do these authentication with OAuth.

If you have to authenticate with email and password, I think you can try to create a user table store for user email & password.

For example, [creating a Mobile Service table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj193162.aspx) and using the [`tables object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj614364.aspx) & [`table object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554210.aspx) to retrieve users for authenticating users.